# How to get linux direcory/file permission string using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to get permission string like **drwxr-xr-x**, **drwxrwxr-x** in python:

```
 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Dec 12 18:46 mount_test2
 drwxrwxr-x 2 root root 4.0K Dec 12 18:47 mount_test
```

Comment: `os.system('ls -l')` perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `subprocess` module and get the answer like this:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p = Popen(['ls', '-l', 'path/to/your/dir'], stdout = PIPE, stderr = PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
```

Your `out` variable will contain the answer you want and you can process it like this:

```
for elem in out.split('\n'):
    permission = elem.split(' ')[0]
```

but there are many ways to process the strings you get in your output.

NOTE FOR PYTHON3: the output needs to be decoded before:

```
out = out.decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Thank you. I need to check in a particular directory. like **/tmp/test**. How can i do this?

Comment: By specifying the directory in your `ls -l` command, I'll update my answer.

Comment: some times it shows a type error in `for elem in out.split('\n'):`  TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: This TypeError only shows in python 3+ version. In python2.7 it working well

Comment: Right, in python3 you need to decode your byte-like object before: `out = out.decode('utf-8')`

Comment: Got it it worked. `out = out.decode('utf-8')`. Thanks man. keep it up

Answer (score 0):

what you are really looking for is sth. like this:

```
stats_flags = [
    (stat.S_IRUSR, "r"),
    (stat.S_IWUSR, "w"),
    (stat.S_IXUSR, "x"),
    (stat.S_IRGRP, "r"),
    (stat.S_IWGRP, "w"),
    (stat.S_IXGRP, "x"),
    (stat.S_IROTH, "r"),
    (stat.S_IWOTH, "w"),
    (stat.S_IXOTH, "x"),
]

def get_permission_string_of_item(itempath):
    perms = os.stat(itempath).st_mode
    perm_string = ""
    for stats in stats_flags:
        if stats[0] and perms:
            perm_string += stats[1]
        else:
            perm_string += "-"

    return perm_string
```